# Why EntityFramework is throwing a Transaction count Error for a storedprocedure with transaction and RAISERROR?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

This is my stored procedure with output string parameter.

```
Create
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpTest]
    (@ReturnMessage varchar(50) output)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            RAISERROR('asdf',16,1)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(50)= ERROR_MESSAGE();

            IF ( @ErrorMessage = 'asdf' )
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnMessage = @ErrorMessage;
                    RETURN;
                END;
            ELSE


            THROW;
        END CATCH;
    END;
```

I am trying manually catch the error with Raiserror and send the error as an output paramter. 
The procedure works fine when i try to execute it from management studio but when I execute from my application the entity framework throws me this error
:

```
SqlException: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

But if I remove the RAISERROR it works fine.

I am using C# MVC application with entity framework version 6.
This is my C# code:

```
public ReturnMessageModel Test()
        {
            ReturnMessageModel result = new ReturnMessageModel();
            ObjectParameter returnMessage = new ObjectParameter("ReturnMessage", typeof(String));
            using (InsurestEntities db = new InsurestEntities())
            {
           db.SpTest(returnMessage);
            }
                result.ReturnMessage = returnMessage.Value.ToString();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

UPDATE: I found the error when I removed this code, the Transaction count error was automatically resolved.

```
IF ( @ErrorMessage = 'asdf' )
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnMessage = @ErrorMessage;
                    RETURN;
                END;
```

Its working fine now. I think the `RAISEERROR` must be always handled by `THROW` statement when used with `EntityFramework`

Comment: Probably you have transaction in C# code. `ROLLBACK TRAN` will rollback all transactions. [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=57d806aff044ebba5d1b2f5091cdde24) and [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) **`The rollback of a nested transaction rolls back the entire set of transactions – as there is no such thing as a nested transaction.`** One way is to change error handling inside SP using SAVEPOINTS.

Comment: No I don't have transaction in C# code. I have updated my question with my c# code too.

Comment: **[SAVE TRANSACTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql)** Please check example how to handle transaction and error inside SP.

Comment: thanks for the alternative way. however I want to know the exact error that I am doing in the code above. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You *do* have transactions in the C# code, you are just not aware of them and not explicitly creating them. EF is creating its own TransactionScope for certain operations.

Your error handling in the presence of transactions in this stored procedure will not work. You already discovered one reason why. You will also run into other issues, like attempting to rollback when there is no transaction. A CATCH block **must** check the [`XACT_STATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql) value inside the block and act accordingly.

If you want a correct errror handling pattern in presence of transactions, see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
go
```

Comment: What is the point of `lbexit:` label? `GOTO` should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

> The procedure works fine when i try to execute it from management studio

It works because you aren't inside active transaction. Let's emulate the same behaviour as C# code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpTest]    (@ReturnMessage varchar(50) output)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            RAISERROR('asdf',16,1)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(50)= ERROR_MESSAGE();

            IF ( @ErrorMessage = 'asdf' )
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnMessage = @ErrorMessage;
                    RETURN;
                END;
            ELSE


            THROW;
        END CATCH;
    END;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.[spTest] 'a'
COMMIT;
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=57d806aff044ebba5d1b2f5091cdde24)**

> Msg 266 Level 16 State 2 Line 0
>
> **Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.**
>
> Msg 3902 Level 16 State 1 Line 4
>
> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

---

Using C#/EF you have opened transaction and it counts. Now in SQL Server there is no such thing as nested transactions. I highly recommend to read [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

> **The rollback of a nested transaction rolls back the entire set of transactions – as there is no such thing as a nested transaction.**

---

What you should do is to correctly handle transaction inside stored procedure. For example using [SAVE TRANSACTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql)

> The following example shows how to use a transaction savepoint to roll back only the modifications made by a stored procedure if an active transaction is started before the stored procedure is executed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveTranExample  
    @InputCandidateID INT  
AS  
    -- Detect whether the procedure was called  
    -- from an active transaction and save  
    -- that for later use.  
    -- In the procedure, @TranCounter = 0  
    -- means there was no active transaction  
    -- and the procedure started one.  
    -- @TranCounter > 0 means an active  
    -- transaction was started before the   
    -- procedure was called.  
    DECLARE @TranCounter INT;  
    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;  
    IF @TranCounter > 0  
        -- Procedure called when there is  
        -- an active transaction.  
        -- Create a savepoint to be able  
        -- to roll back only the work done  
        -- in the procedure if there is an  
        -- error.  
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
    ELSE  
        -- Procedure must start its own  
        -- transaction.  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
    -- Modify database.  
    BEGIN TRY  
        DELETE HumanResources.JobCandidate  
            WHERE JobCandidateID = @InputCandidateID;  
        -- Get here if no errors; must commit  
        -- any transaction started in the  
        -- procedure, but not commit a transaction  
        -- started before the transaction was called.  
        IF @TranCounter = 0  
            -- @TranCounter = 0 means no transaction was  
            -- started before the procedure was called.  
            -- The procedure must commit the transaction  
            -- it started.  
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
        -- An error occurred; must determine  
        -- which type of rollback will roll  
        -- back only the work done in the  
        -- procedure.  
        IF @TranCounter = 0  
            -- Transaction started in procedure.  
            -- Roll back complete transaction.  
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        ELSE  
            -- Transaction started before procedure  
            -- called, do not roll back modifications  
            -- made before the procedure was called.  
            IF XACT_STATE() <> -1  
                -- If the transaction is still valid, just  
                -- roll back to the savepoint set at the  
                -- start of the stored procedure.  
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;  
                -- If the transaction is uncommitable, a  
                -- rollback to the savepoint is not allowed  
                -- because the savepoint rollback writes to  
                -- the log. Just return to the caller, which  
                -- should roll back the outer transaction.  

        -- After the appropriate rollback, echo error  
        -- information to the caller.  
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();  
        SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();  
        SELECT @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
                   @ErrorState -- State.  
                   );  
    END CATCH  
GO
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. You can't rollback without checking `XACT_STATE()`,  even when `@Trancounter` is 0. There are exceptions that, when caught, the transaction *was already rolled back*, the most trivial example being 1205 (deadlock).